# Сепарация обьектов для нейронной сети

Tags: python, изображения, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, обработка-изображений

Я новичок в нейронных сетях и хотел бы разобраться правильно ли я понимаю процес приготовления изображения для детекции объекта. Допустим на входе я получаю текущее изображение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне надо создать сеть, которая классифицирует данные фигуры (точнее определяет, где на изображении находяться окружности). Собственно говоря хочу понять алгоритм обработки изображения до того момента, как в игру входит нейронная сеть.

Я немного информации нашел на эту тему, поэтому сам представил себе такой тривиальный алгоритм:

1. Определение граней всех фигур.
2. Создание контура на основе данных о гранях.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Вырезание каждого контура и запись в например 28х28px

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Классификация каждого новополученного изображения с помощью нейронной сети.

[**Собственно говоря вопрос**] : Правильно ли я понимаю сам процесс подготовки изображения или вообще не в ту степь, и если все же нет, то можете посоветовать пример или литературу. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если все делать по феншую, то ничего (почти) делать до того момента, как "в игру входит нейронная сеть" не надо. Нейросеть сама должна уметь выполнить те действия, что вы описали. Это если мы говорим именно об этапе распознавания, а не об этапе обучения нейронной сети.

Не знаю, на каком уровне понимания нейросетей вы находитесь, но советую начать с начала -  с уяснения того, что такое нейросеть, как она обучается, а как - работает. Для этого подойдет любая книга по Deep Learning. А уж потом можно разбираться и с тем, как распознавать объекты. Ну, например, вот по этим статьям:

https://habr.com/ru/company/jetinfosystems/blog/498652/

https://towardsdatascience.com/image-classification-in-data-science-422855878d2a

Answer (score 1):

Распознание одной фигуры черно-белой - деление ее пикселей на 255 и обучение.Выделение фигуры это уже другое)